# Easy way to get result status code of "systemd-run <command>"?

Tags: linux, virtualization, systemd

It seems the result status code of `systemd-run <command>` is always `0` unless invoking the run-time systemd unit fails.

**Example 1:**

```
$ sudo systemd-run /usr/bin/true
Running as unit run-12255.service.
$ echo $?
0

$ sudo systemd-run /usr/bin/false
Running as unit run-12258.service.
$ echo $?
0
```

I can know whether the command was successfully done or not as follows.

**Example 2:**

```
$ systemctl status $(sudo systemd-run /usr/bin/true 2>&1 | awk '{ print $4 }' | sed -e 's/\.$//')
● run-13004.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
$ echo $?
3

$ systemctl status $(sudo systemd-run /usr/bin/false 2>&1 | awk '{ print $4 }' | sed -e 's/\.$//')
● run-13021.service - /usr/bin/false
   Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/system/run-13021.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/system/run-13021.service.d
           └─50-Description.conf, 50-ExecStart.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2015-08-08 07:31:10 UTC; 15ms ago
  Process: 13024 ExecStart=/usr/bin/false (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 13024 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
$ echo $?
3
```

But the returned code is always `3` since it is the result of `systemctl status` command.
Finally, I have to do as follows;

**Example 3:**

```
$ systemctl status $(sudo systemd-run /usr/bin/true 2>&1 | awk '{ print $4 }' | sed -e 's/\.$//') | (egrep -m 1 -o 'code=exited, status=[0-9]+'| egrep -o '[0-9]+') || echo '0'
0

$ systemctl status $(sudo systemd-run /usr/bin/false 2>&1 | awk '{ print $4 }' | sed -e 's/\.$//') | (egrep -m 1 -o 'code=exited, status=[0-9]+'| egrep -o '[0-9]+') || echo '0'
1
```

This is too weird!

The reason why I use `systemd-run` and get the return code is that I want to execute one or more command in a running `systemd-nspawn`ed container environment (by `systemd-run --machine=my_container`).

To summarize, I want to execute a command in a `systemd-nspawn`ed container and get the result code just like `docker exec` (without `machinectl login` since I want to execute so many commands by non-interactive script file).
Can anyone kindly let me know easy way to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems the result status code of systemd-run  is always 0
>   unless invoking the run-time systemd unit fails.

Yes, that's the correct and expected behaviour.. systemd-run does not run the command by itself in this particular case. it creates, validates and en-queues a transient .service file with the parameters you choose, which then started by either the "--system" or "--user" service manager. 
To get what you want .. TL;DR

```
# systemd-run --scope /bin/true
# echo $?
0
# systemd-run --scope /bin/false
# echo $?
1
```

Note that in this case, the scope unit will inherit the environment of the calling script and execution only returns when the command finishes..

Comment: Thanks! It works well in case of normal `systemd-run --scope`, but does not work in case of `systemd-run --scope --machine=my_container`. The error message is `Scope execution is not supported on non-local systems.`.

Comment: @takaomag you are out of luck then unfortunately.. this particular feature is intentionally not implemented..

Comment: @CristianRodriguez Any ideas why `systemd-run --scope --slice=test sleep 5` ends up in the `system.slice` instead of `test.slice`?

Comment: @AlexBrand there is no validation in place to check if the slice exists, neither a new one is created. I am not sure if it is a documentation bug .. (missing "slice must exists") or a bug "systemd-run should create the a transient slice too"

Comment: @CristianRodriguez I tested this with an existing and active slice, and it still does not work. Does it work for you? I created https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2991

Answer (score 2):

You need to to use `--remain-after-exit` to tell Systemd to keep service unit, so that it is possible to get its status.

```
# systemd-run  --unit=kek$RANDOM --remain-after-exit     bash -c 'sleep 2; id; exit 216'
Running as unit kek30537.service.

# systemctl show  kek30537.service  -p ExecMainStatus
ExecMainStatus=216
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the particulars of `systemd`-based virtualization, but if you need the return codes of previous commands to decide whether to run further commands, or to decide what further commands to run, an easy solution would probably be to put your commands (**not** prefixed with `sudo systemd-run`) *together with* all the return code querying and according decision logic into a script.

Then simply invoke that script with `sudo systemd-run /path/to/that/script`.